# git create branch from hash with out fetching

Tags: git, git-push

I'm working on scripting some git commands for managing releases. One thing I would like to do if create a branch on the remote server using a hash on the remote server. But I'd like to run this without the overhead of having to fetch an entire tree. I get the hash from `git ls-remote <url>` then I want to push to the remote as well via something like `git push <url> <hash>:refs/heads/release/1.0.0` but in order for this to work I need to init a repository, then do a fetch the hash.

I'm hoping there is a more direct way than having to fetch first.  and I should note I'm hopefully optimizing the extra steps by initializing a bare repo, then doing a shallow fetch with depth=1.

Comment: So your remote API has no way to say just "make a branch"?

Comment: @matt I started to look into bitbucket clouds REST api, and got hung up with the basics of authentication, doh! That would likely be the better approach I was short on time and wasn't able to learn the REST api soon enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Except for a very few commands `git` works only with the local repository; the limited set of subcommands is: `clone`, `fetch`, `pull`, `push`, `ls-remote`.

So to work with remote repository you have 3 alternatives:

1. Use an out-of-`git` API provided by the remote host. Examples are Github/Gitlab APIs.
2. Connect to the remote host using `ssh` and work with the remote repository locally, directly at the server.
3. Clone locally; fetch just enough to create and push a branch.

The end of the list.

Comment: Thank you, I was kind of expecting this. I'm basically doing #3 already

Answer (score 2):

If that repo's yours, just make the branch there: the way to do it is sign in on the server and make the branches.

If it's not yours, push ordinary updates: you don't get to bypass the checks on what gets pushed to repos that aren't yours. The definition of "yours" is, you can sign on to the server and use the local git commands, like for instance making arbitrary branches.

Yes, I'm basically echoing [what @phd said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66180657/1290731).

Edit: one addition: to fetch the absolute minimum necessary to do the task you asked for, do your clone `-n --filter=tree:0 --depth 1 --no-single-branch`, then you can add refs to existing commits and push those at a 99+% discount (in my test) on fetch cost.

Comment: Thank you for the additional parameters, I knew about `--depth 1` and was using that already. I'll look up the other options to see what they do.